# System properties: user.region or user.country

Tags: java

I searched after which are the system properties for the default locale. I found many places something like that: `user.language` (it worked) and `user.region` (wont work). After a deeper search I found a `user.country` (which kinda worked - returned with the result what supposed to be returned by the `user.region`).

So how is that? Those reference are all wrong or did I miss something?

Comment: Why are you trying to access these properties instead of using the java.util.Locale methods?

Comment: Only to understand the mechanism. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to see the system properties involved in the calculation of the default Locale directly in the JDK source code:

```
public static Locale getDefault() {
    // do not synchronize this method - see 4071298
    // it's OK if more than one default locale happens to be created
    if (defaultLocale == null) {
        String language, region, country, variant;
        language = AccessController.doPrivileged(
            new GetPropertyAction("user.language", "en"));
        // for compatibility, check for old user.region property
        region = AccessController.doPrivileged(
            new GetPropertyAction("user.region"));
        if (region != null) {
            // region can be of form country, country_variant, or _variant
            int i = region.indexOf('_');
            if (i >= 0) {
                country = region.substring(0, i);
                variant = region.substring(i + 1);
            } else {
                country = region;
                variant = "";
            }
        } else {
            country = AccessController.doPrivileged(
                new GetPropertyAction("user.country", ""));
            variant = AccessController.doPrivileged(
                new GetPropertyAction("user.variant", ""));
        }
        defaultLocale = getInstance(language, country, variant);
    }
    return defaultLocale;
}
```

From the code, user.language is always used. user.region seems to deprecated by user.country and user.variant. However it is used for compatibility reasons. Code comments should provide enough information to understand how region and country properties work.